# Is there a way to undefine a function in emacs lisp?

Tags: function, emacs, elisp

I have a macro that creates function. It creates interactive functions based on current opened buffer. However, it starts to flood the M-x after a long running section. Is there a way to make a function invalid?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [`fmakunbound`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Cells.html):

```
(fmakunbound 'my-boring-function)
```